# Which databases use .bas files for storing data

Tags: database, file-format

I have a program that stores it's database in .bas files I would like to read. Is it possible those files have some standard database format?

The program is written in Delphi

Comment: A .bas file could be almost anything.  You need to provide more information besides just the extension.

Comment: @Amy There is no something human readable inside those files, except some string values, that program represent showing database data. Files start from different hex codes: 2F 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 - one file, 08 37 38 2F - other...